# Modal Dialog box is shown below the launching screen in windows 10

Tags: c#

In one of our windows apps, a dialog box is launched using MessageBox.Show, which is working fine on win 7 and 8. But on Win 10, the popup is shown below the launcher. Any guess how to rectify this?

thanks

Comment: Please can you clarify your question a little? Can you show some code? Do you mean a splash screen with _launcher_? What UI framework are you using (`WPF`, `WinForms` or something different)? Without further details, you question can't be answered...

Comment: sorry, the form is launched from another library which I don't have access to. However I worked on the actual form..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the MessageBox.Show overload that allows you to specific a parent window:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cked7698(v=vs.110).aspx

If you are using WPF/UWP, you can write something like this:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, 
    () => MessageBox.Show(Application.Current.MainWindow, msg));
```

An alternative way to hack the same functionality without a specific window is this:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, 
    () => MessageBox.Show(new Form { TopMost = true }, msg);
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer. The form launch is called from a library and it is outside of my area. That team took ownership of this issue. I forwarded your answer to them. Once again thanks for your input!